# after passing a state to my useState hook, it is undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using google youtube api to stream some video. Unfortunately I got stuck on passing video details, when a users clicks on a video.
(I am aware of the warning, will fix this soon by adding of an index to the thumbnail).

The question is (it is also in the middle of the post, but am afraid, that it will get lost): why hss my `searchedValue.videos` changed to undefined?

I got a working version:
When I click on a thumbnail of a video, I get the expected result.
[image: picture of my working version]

Here is the code for it:

App.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import youtube from "../apis/youtube";
import VideoList from "./VideoList";
import VideoDetail from "./VideoDetail";

export const VideoContext = createContext();

function App() {
    const [ searchedValue, setSearchedValue ] = useState({ videos: [], selectedVideo: null });

    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

    const handleSearch = async (inputText) => {
        const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
            params: {
                q: inputText,
                part: "snippet",
                type: "video",
                maxResults: 5,
                key: API_KEY
            }
        });
        setSearchedValue({ videos: response.data.items });
    };

    const handleSelectedVideo = (singleRenderedVideo) => {
        console.log("from App.js: ", singleRenderedVideo);
        // setSearchedValue({ selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo });
    };

    return (
        <div className="ui container">
            <NavBar handleSearch={handleSearch} />
            <VideoContext.Provider value={handleSelectedVideo}>
                <p>I got {searchedValue.videos.length} results.</p>
                {/* <VideoDetail video={searchedValue.selectedVideo} /> */}
                <VideoList handleSelectedVideo={handleSelectedVideo} listOfVideos={searchedValue.videos} />
            </VideoContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

---

NavBar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const NavBar = (props) => {
    const [ inputText, setInputText ] = useState("");

    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        props.handleSearch(inputText);
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setInputText(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div className="search-bar ui segment">
            <form onSubmit={handleSearch} className="ui form">
                <div className="field">
                    <label>Video Search</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Type in to search for videos"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={inputText}
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

---

VideoDetail.js

```
import React from "react";

const VideoDetail = ({ video }) => {
    if (!video) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>;
};

export default VideoDetail;
```

---

VideoItem.js

```
import "./VideoItem.css";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { VideoContext } from "./App";

const VideoItem = ({ singleRenderedVideo }) => {
    const videoContext = useContext(VideoContext);
    return (
        <div onClick={() => videoContext(singleRenderedVideo)} className="video-item item">
            <img className="ui image" src={singleRenderedVideo.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url} alt="img" />
            <div className="content">
                <div className="header">{singleRenderedVideo.snippet.title}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default VideoItem;
```

---

VideoList.js

```
import React from "react";
import VideoItem from "./VideoItem";

const VideoList = ({ listOfVideos }) => {
    const renderedListOfVideos = listOfVideos.map((video) => {
        return <VideoItem singleRenderedVideo={video} />;
    });
    return <div className="ui relaxed divided list">{renderedListOfVideos}</div>;
};

export default VideoList;
```

---

**But in App.js, when I try to set the state of `selectedVideo`:**

```
const handleSelectedVideo = (singleRenderedVideo) => {
        // console.log("from App.js: ", singleRenderedVideo);
        setSearchedValue({ selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo });
    };
```

**I get the following error:**

[image: not working version]

The whole App.js, where the code is changed.

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import youtube from "../apis/youtube";
import VideoList from "./VideoList";
import VideoDetail from "./VideoDetail";

export const VideoContext = createContext();

function App() {
    const [ searchedValue, setSearchedValue ] = useState({ videos: [], selectedVideo: null });

    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

    const handleSearch = async (inputText) => {
        const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
            params: {
                q: inputText,
                part: "snippet",
                type: "video",
                maxResults: 5,
                key: API_KEY
            }
        });
        setSearchedValue({ videos: response.data.items });
    };

    const handleSelectedVideo = (singleRenderedVideo) => {
        // console.log("from App.js: ", singleRenderedVideo);
        setSearchedValue({ selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo });
    };

    return (
        <div className="ui container">
            <NavBar handleSearch={handleSearch} />
            <VideoContext.Provider value={handleSelectedVideo}>
                <p>I got {searchedValue.videos.length} results.</p>
                <VideoDetail video={searchedValue.selectedVideo} />
                <VideoList handleSelectedVideo={handleSelectedVideo} listOfVideos={searchedValue.videos} />
            </VideoContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class components, if you set state and provide only a partial object, react will do a shallow merge with the full state. This does not happen in function components. Whatever you set the state to, that's the state. So this code:

```
setSearchedValue({ selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo })
```

...will set the state to an object with a selectedVideo property only. It no longer has a videos property.

You have two options:

1. do a shallow merge yourself

```
setSearchedValue(previous => ({
  ...previous,
  selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo
}));
```

2. Have two separate state variables. For a case like yours, i recommend doing it this way.

```
const [ videos, setVideos ] = useState([]);
const [ selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo ] = useState(null);

// ...

setSelectedVideo(singleRenderedVideo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
However I have one more question about #2:
in the setSelectedVideo(singleRenderedVideo) you do not use the value selectedVideo. Is it o.k. to do like this?

Comment: Well, in the code you provided the new value is unrelated to the old value, so there's no need to use the old value. If you do need to use the old value  (such as because you're incrementing a counter), it's usually a good idea to use the function version of setState, as in `setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The searchedValue is set to {selectedVideo:...}. The other property because the new value does not have that property. You should include your videos property when you set searchedValue. It should be setSearchedValue ({...searchedValue, selectedVideo: newValue})

Comment: Thanks for getting me back on the right way. In your solution however it is not enough to do setSearchedValue ({...searchedValue, selectedVideo: newValue}). The answer provided by Nicholas Tower with setSearchedValue(previous => ({
  ...previous,
  selectedVideo: singleRenderedVideo
}));
works.